# IP Mask with asterisks using jQuery - E.g. 192.168.1.*

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, ip, mask

I'm using this cdn → 
(`https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html`) to implement an IP input mask →

```
$('.ipMask').mask('099.099.099.099', { 
    pattern: /[\*0-9]/g 
});
```

But I still can't type asterisks (`*`) in the input field !

I want to type IP addresses like this: `192.168.1.*`

Could someone help me please? :)

Comment: It would be better if you gave a link to the documentation than the minified code.

Comment: Is it this: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html ? It doesn't have a `pattern` option, except as part of the `translation` option.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved! :)

For those who want to know the solution :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.ip_address').mask('XZZ.XZZ.XZZ.XZZ', {
    translation: {
        'Z': {
            pattern: /[0-9:\*]/g, optional: true,
        },

        'X': {
            pattern: /[0-2:\*]/g, optional: false,
        }
    }
});
```

});